# Possible to view yesterday's version of a hopefully cached JavaScript file in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, icloud, browser-cache, icloud-drive

Using Chrome 61. iCloud Drive mysteriously seems to have reverted a JavaScript file I worked a long time on to a previous version (before I did a `git commit`). I had viewed this file repeatedly in Chrome (`src`ed from an html page). Is it possible Chrome still has a copy of this somewhere?

Any other way I could possible recover this file? iCloud Drive doesn't appear to have revision history as I thought (I can only recover *deleted* files).

Comment: Try a text search in the browser profile cache directory using a unique text that was present in the old version. Note, if the files are gzipped you'll need a proper command line pipe.

Comment: @wOxxOm Where would I find that on a Mac? I found a cache directory at `~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache`, but the files are a binary format. Not gzip files according to `gunzip`.

Answer (score 2):

Pheww, I got it!

1. Shut down my web server
2. Loaded the page in Chrome
3. Chrome expectedly reported the server refused the connection
4. Clicked view page source
5. There it was!

Comment: Did the "server refused the connection" error page have a link offering to show you a cached version of the page, or did you right-click and select **View Page Source**?

Comment: @KayceBasques I had to right click *View Page Source*. I didn’t even know if that would work, but it did! There were no links on the connection refused page.

Comment: I'm happy it worked for you but that sounds a bit unexpected / buggy to me. If I clicked View Page Source, I'd expect it to show the page source of Chrome's error page. I'm only pointing this out because I fear that others may not be able to rely on this in the feature. Thanks for sharing your knowledge, though.

Comment: @KayceBasques you are correct, this may not always work. Though I saw no other obvious way to get the cached content. Hopefully this works for someone else in the same situation in the future...